# strtotime not working in php for HH:MM:SS format

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a duration like this: 211:30:24. I have to compare whether it's greater than other duration like 01:00:00. I am using strtotime function to change duration into int and then comparing it.

But the problem is strtotime(211:30:24) is returning false. Up to 24:00:00, it's working fine.

I am using below code:

```
$duration = strtotime('211:30:24');
if($duration >= strtotime ( '01:00:00' )){
  return true;
}else{
 return false;
}
```

$duration is false.

I am using php5.1. Anybody have idea why it's happening.

Comment: Common add your code we cannot guess your fault.

Comment: `211:30:24` is not a valid time. Take a look at `var_dump($duration);`. `strtotime` is for parsing dates and times, not durations, and there are only 24 hours in a day.

Comment: Yup.. Now i got it mate. Thanks. I have to look into some otherway to compare these two durations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php

the time you specified is not valid, valid time format is mentioned in the document

Comment: ya mate, i went in the wrong direction. At first i thought it was time. :(